# Only one product url hitting from different IP

Tags: magento-1.9

**tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log**
after using this command I got know same product is hitting again & gain from different IP.

```
1.136.106.111 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /js/prototype/prototype.js HTTP/1.1" 200 32325 ""**SAME PRODUCT URL**" " "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SAMSUNG SM-G975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/11.0 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36"
69.117.173.13 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /media/wysiwyg/authrize.png HTTP/1.1" 200 9604 ""**SAME PRODUCT URL**" " "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
69.117.173.13 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /media/wysiwyg/trus.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7429 ""**SAME PRODUCT URL**" " "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
85.255.234.23 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /skin/frontend/cendo/ma_cendo3/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 34341 ""SAME PRODUCT URL" " "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
1.136.106.111 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /js/scriptaculous/effects.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7492 ""**SAME PRODUCT URL**" " "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SAMSUNG SM-G975F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/11.0 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36"
69.117.173.13 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /media/wysiwyg/ssl.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7892 ""**SAME PRODUCT URL**" " "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
85.255.234.23 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /skin/frontend/cendo/ma_cendo3/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 24579 ""SAME PRODUCT URL" " "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
85.255.234.23 - - [13/Feb/2020:10:48:55 +0000] "GET /skin/frontend/cendo/ma_cendo3/css/bootstrap-theme.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7568 "**SAME PRODUCT URL**" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
```

I think they are not bots, How to stop hitting the same product URL again & again from different IP? Actually I am facing Ram issue & Magento site down again & again.

Thanks.

Comment: Each page view is going to result in multiple requests for CSS, JS, images, etc. Are you sure that there is a problem?

Comment: If your store is going down when you have too much online users, as you are using apache2 instead nginx, maybe you got many threads at same time, apache2 for default cannot handle well this. Nginx is better to handle many simultaneous users (https://serverguy.com/comparison/apache-vs-nginx/). 
I would check the database process list too, innodb can stuck sometimes (too much sleep process) and the magento can go down

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? @abhishek

Comment: I did not get any solution but I have solved the problem by disabling that product. Still, the Same product URL  is hitting from outside. As that product is disable so,  no query has been executed so, no waiting queue of mysql query of product.

Comment: Still, I am searching for a better solution. You can disable your same product for a short period of time until you get a proper solution. it will solve the  Magento site down  issue.